How to convert PowerAutomate approval date stamp to a more readable format
I have a SharePoint List, updated by a PowerAutomate approval workflow.  I'm using Send HTTP Request To SharePoint to do the updating of the relevant fields.
My SharePoint column entitled "Approval/Rejection" date, pulls the approval/rejection date through OK, but it's in this format "2024-08-30T12:58:05Z2024-08-30T12:58:05Z".
Is there a way to convert this to a more readable format, either in PA before it populates the SharePoint column, or even in Sharepoint using a Calculated Column to somehow extract the date part and convert it?
Have tried messing with the format in PA and SharePoint, but I think it's maybe the syntax that's throwing me at this point.

not sure if formatting it inside PA will make any differences, because dates in SharePoint will always be stored in UTC.. you may change the date format inside the site regional settings. Also how you are showing the data using SharePoint list views? if so then list views will do this job for you,, they will never show the date in this format 2024-08-30T12:58:05Z2024-08-30T12:58:05Z , they format the date/time based on the regional setting you have

Ah OK. Within PA I'm picking up the approval response date from the list item by initializing a variable and using a string, then using a Send HTTP Request to Sharepoint action to update a rich text field in my list. I guess there is some way to avoid picking up the date as text? I'm new to the PA game so still finding my feet with it all.

ok if you are update sharepoint list item rich text field with the data, then u will need to format it by yourself, you can use formatDateTime() such as formatDateTime('2009-06-15T13:45:30', 'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt') // Returns the format 6/15/2009 .. or formatDateTime('2009-06-15T13:45:30', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt') // Returns the format 6/15/2009 13:45:30 PM.. and so on

did my below answer fixed your issue? if so, can you please accept it so it will be useful for others?

Thanks, yes.  I applied your suggested expression to a separate "date" variable which I created, then got the HTTP request to update my date text field using the new variable.  It looks like I wanted, so great, thanks for that!  The only thing I need to do next is somehow turn that date text into a date/time-format so people can filter it and create formulae using it (like viewing items within the last XX weeks etc).  I think I can probably do that conversion using a calculated field in the SharePoint list.  But yes, your help enabled me to get the date into a much more readable/usable format!

@Phil Edwards If you are updating SharePoint list item's rich text field with the date value, then u will need to format the date by yourself. sharePoint stores the date/time in UTC,  you can use formatDateTime() such as formatDateTime('2009-06-15T13:45:30', 'M/dd/yyyy h:mm tt') which will returns the format 6/15/2009. Or formatDateTime('2009-06-15T13:45:30', 'M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt') which will return the format 6/15/2009 13:45:30 PM. Or formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'MMMM dd, yyyy, HH:mm') which will returns the current date time in the format June 15, 2009, 16:50. and so on..

Default SharePoint format is M/dd/yyyy, so simply formatting your date in this format should work. Or if there happens to a custom form just peek into tha column to get the exact format.
